# Core java basics

Tags: java

How can I update the only `str2` by not really updating `str1` and `str`? Why is the change in `str2` is updating `str1` and `str`? Is it because of the object reference?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {

    List<HashMap<String, String>> str;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hmap.put("1", "s1");
        hmap.put("2", "s2");
        test testobj = new test();
        testobj.str = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        testobj.str.add((HashMap<String, String>) hmap);
        testing(testobj.str);
    }

    static void testing(List<HashMap<String, String>> str) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> str2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> str1 = str;
        str2.add(str1.get(0));
        str2.get(0).put("1", "new");

        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println(str2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's because object reference.

Comment: so, how i can make str ultimately non editable?

Comment: Like completely non editable or just have it not updated by other object references?

Comment: If you want a deep copy of `str`, you can do `str.stream().map(HashMap::new).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @GBlodgett yes, not updated by any other object reference

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a copy of the original `List` like this:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> str1 = new ArrayList<>(str);
```

which creates a new `ArrayList` containing all the elements from the original `List`. This way you'll have two separate list containing its own elements.

Comment: OP isn't modifying the original list.

Comment: not working :( its still updating all lists

Comment: If you mean updating the HashMap inside the List, this is expected because you are adding the first HashMap inside str1 to str2: str2.add(str1.get(0)); After that you extract this same HashMap from str2 and put an element in it: str2.get(0).put("1", "new");. You are updating exactly the same HashMap. BTW, your code is very confusing. The str1 variable has no practical effect since it references the same List as str.

Comment: So, how should I optimise it so I can have reference of str in str2 maybe and still have it not updated by str2?